# Microsoft VSCode C/C++ IntelliSense shows false errors about Windows.h MACROS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, intellisense

This program compiles well. It is the microsoft C/CPP Intellisense that shows errors. The errors have been commented out below. The Origin of these errors I suspect are from the Windows.h file because it doesn't let me use the WINAPI keyword.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define local_persist static
#define global_variable static
#define internal static

#define pi32 3.14159265359f

typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef uint32 bool32;

#include <Windows.h>

// typedef int __stdcall test(int x, int y)
// expected a ';'C/C++(65)
typedef int WINAPI test(int x, int y);

// int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
// expected a ';'C/C++(65)
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

    int num;
    num = 5;

    while(true){
        // nothing here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any clue what might be triggering this intellisense errors? Ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: You missed semi-colon in those statements. The error also says that.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I did not miss a semicolon. Like I said, the code compiles and givens the desire output. When I use `__stdcall` though which is the definition of `WINAPI` everything works well. Why isn't intellisense reading the proper macros?